# Регулярка на PHP - Работа с цифрами и заменами

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

В php есть строка. Состоит из чего угодно, что можно набрать с клавиатуры, в любом количестве и в любом порядке/последовательности.
Требуется регулярка, которая уберет всё, кроме цифр. Такие цифры должны быть разделены пробелами. Несколькозначную цифру пробелами не(!) делить - такое число остается "как есть". Дробное число разделяется на два, разделитель заменяется на пробел.

Comment: Приведите ваши попытки решения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял то это простая регулярка типа этого.

```
/[^0-9\.]/
```

А на `php` все это дело будет выглядеть так.

```
$string = 'asdg456asdg4a64asd65g4asd6ggadsgasdg5.6adgasdg asdg asdg';
preg_replace('/[^0-9\.]/', ' ', $string);
```

Вот [ссылка](https://regex101.com/r/QqyV3m/1) для проверки регулярки.